# How can I create a datetime64[D] in numba

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I need to pass dates into numba function.

Passing them in as .astype('datetime64[D]') works well. But I need to create an epoch date inside function too.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numba
from numba import jit
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def datetime_range(start, end, delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta



@jit(nopython=True)
def myfunc(dts):
    epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01').astype('datetime64[D]')
    if epoch == dts[0]:
        n = 1
    return epoch


dts = [dt for dt in
       datetime_range(datetime(2016, 9, 1, 7), datetime(2016, 9, 2,7),
       timedelta(minutes=15))]

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(index = dts)

res = myfunc(pandas_df.index.values.astype('datetime64[D]'))

print(res)
```

I get error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'astype' of type datetime64[]

File "test5.py", line 17:
def myfunc(dts):
    epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01').astype('datetime64[D]')
    ^

During: typing of get attribute at C:/Users/PUser/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectTEST/test5.py (17)

File "test5.py", line 17:
def myfunc(dts):
    epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01').astype('datetime64[D]')
    ^
```

How can I make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely related to [this documented issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6555) with `numba`.

---

A first workaround would be to define `epoch` outside of your `jit` function:

```py
def myfunc(dts):
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def wrapper(dts, epoch):
        if epoch == dts[0]:
            n = 1
        return epoch
    epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01').astype('datetime64[D]')
    return wrapper(dts, epoch)
```

---

An alternative, hacky solution that also comes to mind would be to render your dates as strings before feeding them to `myfunc` :

```
res = myfunc(np.datetime_as_string(pandas_df.index.values, unit='D'))
```

and define `epoch ='1970-01-01'` inside of `myfunc`.

You can finally add a post-processing step after that to convert your strings back to `datetime64` or whatever they need be.

Comment: Thanks for the link, your first option is what I already do, just want to hide that bit inside function. I will accept your answer as it will be useful to others.